# Translation English to japanese

Tags: translation

So I'm trying to say : Always say "Itadakimasu" before eating sushi.

I was wondering if this is the correct way of saying it:

> いつも『いただきます』と言うこと前に寿司を食べります。

Comment: 1) What is Japanese counterpart of English preposition? 2) Check the conjugation of every verb.

Answer (score 4):

> Always say "Itadakimasu" before eating sushi.

Is that imperative?

If that's the case, I think you could say:

> (お)寿司を食べる前には、必ず「いただきます」と｛言いなさい。/ 言ってください。/ 言いましょう。 etc.｝

or:

> (お)寿司は、必ず「いただきます」と言ってから｛食べなさい。/ 食べてください。/ 食べましょう。 etc.｝

Comment: > Is that imperative?  You must be correct. So "I" is a mother and she said to her child "Always say "Itadakimasu" before eating sushi."

Answer (score 3):

### Revised Edition

I realized that the sentence is imperative by Chocolate's answer.

> Always say "Itadakimasu" before eating sushi.

あなたの翻訳｛ほんやく｝：いつも『いただきます』と言｛い｝うこと前｛まえ｝に寿司｛すし｝を食｛た｝べります。

私｛わたし｝の翻訳｛ほんやく｝：寿司｛すし｝を食｛た｝べる前｛まえ｝にいつも「いただきます」と言｛い｝いなさい。

---

### Former Edition

> Always say "Itadakimasu" before eating sushi.

あなたの翻訳｛ほんやく｝：いつも『いただきます』と言｛い｝うこと前｛まえ｝に寿司｛すし｝を食｛た｝べります。

私｛わたし｝の翻訳｛ほんやく｝：寿司｛すし｝を食｛た｝べる前｛まえ｝にいつも「いただきます」と言｛い｝います。